# ITE Imperial breaker box panel

Tags: breaker-box

When I bought my house, the cover and door on the breaker box was missing. I've searched everywhere, what can I do?

Comment: I feel your pain.   We acquired a building with all the service panel covers gone.  The (readily available) CH covers were quickly found under a sheet of plywood.  The (unobtainable) Pushmatic cover was never found.  'Course, we didn't look on eBay...

Answer (score 1):

Imperial hasn't been around since the late 1970s, so finding a replacement panel cover is likely going to be either very difficult or impossible.  You could check to see if a Siemens distributor can source them (they ended up with Imperial's assets through a series of acquisitions), but that would be a long shot.  The best option is likely going to be replacing the panel.

Comment: Would it be up to code if I had one made out of sheet metal and hinged it?

Comment: Thanks, even though I didn't want to hear that. I never get the simple problems:(